# Adaptar todos controles al maximizar una forma

Tags: windows-forms

el problema que tengo con mi programa es que cuando maximizo la forma, todos los controles(son 20 botones y un textbox) se quedan con las misma posicion y tamaño, haciendo que el programa se vea horrible, la solucion mas comun que encuentro es usar las propiedades de dock y anchor, ya lo intente, pero me terminan empeorando todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que deberias hacer un trabajo complejo determinando el tamaño de la ventana cuando este cambia con el evento, y segun esos % cambiar los botones. Porque no le quitas los botones para agrandar y la posibilidad de agrandarlo? normalmente las calculadoras son fijas.

Comment: Coloque una respuesta que es una solución a tu problema, aunque no es elegante que una calculadora se maximice, pero si lo quieres permitir el control ´System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel´es la solución. Prueba mi respuesta y si te resulta, te agradeceria que puntees mi respuesta, seria un estimulo para mi, pues soy un usuario nuevo en el sitio y además soy desarrollador autodidacta.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que querés lograr es que los botones se mantengan siempre, por ejemplo, en el centro del form, independientemente de su tamaño.
En ese caso te recomiendo que encierres todos los controles que quieras manejar dentro de un groupBox.
Luego a este groupBox lo seteas **sin anchors** (Anchor: **None**).

Con esto logras que todo lo contenido en el groupBox (Que deberás alinear correctamente) se mantenga en la misma posición dentro del groupBox, pero este último esté anclado a las posiciones variables del form.

Lo único que tenés que tener en cuenta antes de hacer esto, es posicionar el groupBox a tu gusto con el tamaño de ventana inicial que quieras tener, y luego seteas los anchor como mencioné, caso contrario te va a costar posicionarlo, ya que el anchor afecta tanto en tiempo de ejecución como en tiempo de edición del form.

---

Edit
En el caso de querer también modificar el tamaño de los controles internos, lo que debés hacer es el Anchor del groupBox competo (Top, Bottom, Left, Right) y para cada control interno de este groupbox, setear el AutoSize en true y el AutoSizeMode en GrowAndShrink, esto permite que puedan crecer, pero por un comportamiento de como están diseñados los forms no van a achicar, con lo cual va a deformar tu vista.
Para solucionar esto, a los controles internos del form le seteas la propiedad de dock como mas te guste.

Comment: hice lo que me dijiste, ahora los controles estan en el centro(bien) pero sin embargo el tamaño de los controles es el mismo por lo que se desperdicia mucho espacio. ¿alguna solucion?

Comment: Hola @alansmith, edité mi respuesta. Por favor revisala y si te ayuda no olvides votar mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si es una calculadora lo que estas haciendo lo más común es que sea de dimensiones fijas, para ello colocas la propiedad  `FormBorderStyle` al valor `FixedToolWindow`, pero si aún quieres mantener la opción de dimensionar y maximizar, entonces puedes colocar todos tus controles dentro de una contenedor `System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel`, este control permite definir filas y columnas donde alojar tus controles, tantas como sean necesarias, defines su propiedad `dock` en `Fill` y editas el estilo de las filas y columnas colocando porcentajes, en un valor igual a numero de columnas/100 para las columnas y numero de filas/100 para las filas, las filas y columnas se dimensionaran automáticamente, cada ves que se redimensione el formulario, a los controles les defines la propiedad anchor en `Top|Bottom|Left|Right` y se redimensionaran de manera automática. Si necesitas que un control ocupe más de una columna entonces lo logras estableciendo el valor adecuado de la propiedad `ColumnSpan`, si es varias filas estableces el valor adecuado de la propiedad `RowSpan`